# Volume Control in Processing (java)?

Tags: java, audio, controls, processing, minim

I'm working on a Processing project. I tried to set the Volume of the audio played with the minim library. (`setVolume` seems not to be supported, and `setGain` has no effect)

So, I'm wondering whether there is no other, simpler way to control the audio in Processing? Or are there some Java commands, that can be used directly?

(In fact, I want to fade In and Out a short audio file, which means, I go through a loop and increase the volume after some steps)

I thank for every help!

Greetings
Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Sonia or Beads (both listed [here](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/#sound)). Both of these will let you do what you're after.
I've had nothing but problems with Minim since it was first rolled into Processing; the other libraries are better documented, easier to use and a lot more stable!

Answer (score 1):

I did it now with ESS.

ESS is perfect, because you have also a pause() and resume() function. And it works with MP3's.

thanks for your help!